# what does scope mean here?

Tags: meaning

[image]

I think I underdstand the sentence just couldnt really figure what "scope" really means here. Thanks.

Comment: _Scope_ seems to have its normal, standard, dictionary meaning here. I’m more puzzled by what is meant by “efficient use of the spectrum”, which doesn’t make an awful lot of sense without further context.

Comment: Please note that our Help Centre advises that it's *off-topic* to ask for "The meaning of words, or synonyms for words, unless you have first looked them up in a dictionary or thesaurus." For further guidance, see [ask].

Comment: Thank you for asking. Please do not post text as images. They are not searchable and do not work with assistive devices. Also please [edit] to add details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why.
See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.
Every question should describe prior efforts to find an answer, and explain why the results were not adequate. Some research is required on every question. This is called our research requirement. The link I gave above has more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scope](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scope) is being used here in its most common sense of "opportunity or space for unhampered motion".

"There is scope for X" is a common way of stating that X is allowed or possible. It's common in academic and corporate styles.

What "scope for X" does not convey is whether or not the author thinks that X is a desirable thing or not.  In the quoted example, the meaning is clearly positive, but in a sentence like "There is scope for increased borrowing" it's unclear whether the writer considers that a good or bad thing (contrast with "increased borrowing can occur" which suggests borrowing is bad, versus "allows increased borrowing" which suggests borrowing is good)

In this example, the quoted sentence can be rewritten as "*Technology developments increase the *opportunity* for more efficient use of the spectrum by improving encoding and error correction systems*"

Also worth noting: the phrase "Technology developments" is poor English: yes, one could argue that "technology" is functioning as an adjective here (as in "technology park"), but it still doesn't seem natural -- to this native reader it just looks like there are two nouns ("developments" and "technology") fighting to be the subject of the sentence. Either "*Technological developments*..." (emphasising "developments") or "*Developments in technology*" (emphasising "technology") are more natural.